# How to clear input field onclick?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have done a lot to fix this, but it's not working. I am using *Ionic's searchbar*.
My input field gets the class `ng-empty` when nothing is filled in (so this is the default state). The input field gets a `ng-not-empty` class when it's filled in.

So, I could fix this with `jQuery` or something, but I saw that `Angular` has ways to do this. This is the HTML:

```
 <ion-view view-title="Testing">

     <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar">
      </ion-header-bar>

         <ion-content class="scrollBar">

            <ion-searchbar class="searchBar" ng-app="myApp">
               <label>
                 <input class="searchField" type="search" ng-model="itemsSearch"/>
                  <a class="clear" data-ng-click="saveParentComment()">X</a>
                  <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
              </label>
           </ion-searchbar>

      </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
```

I've added this to my controller:

```
myApp.controller('SearchController', function ($http, $scope, $state) {

 $scope.saveParentComment = function () {
      $scope.itemsSearch = "";
  };
```

Yet, this is not working and I don't get why. Am I doing something wrong? If so, how can I fix it? I have seen a lot of questions regarding this one, but no answer worked for me. I don't see any errors in the console either...

The only thing I see, is that the anchor gets a new class *"activated"* when I click on it.

Comment: post your controller and whole view

Comment: Hi there. I've edited the question for you.

Comment: Why is there an `ng-app` directive in the middle of an `ion-view`? I'm surprised that there is no error message about that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere in your view you have put **`SearchController`** Also ng-model should work with a **`dot`** operator

Try,

```
 <ion-view view-title="Testing"  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SearchController">
     <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar">
      </ion-header-bar>
         <ion-content class="scrollBar">
            <ion-searchbar class="searchBar">
               <label>
                 <input class="searchField" type="search" ng-model="myObj.itemsSearch"/>
                  <a class="clear" data-ng-click="saveParentComment()">X</a>
                  <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
              </label>
           </ion-searchbar>
      </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
```

**In controller:**

```
myApp.controller('SearchController', function ($http, $scope, $state) {
 $scope.myObj = {};
 $scope.saveParentComment = function () {
      $scope.myObj.itemsSearch = "";
};
```

Comment: Doesn't work either. Object seems to break my search functionality

Comment: what do you mean by search functionality?

Comment: Well, when I type something (let's say the letter K"), it gives me all items with the K. With your solution, this doesn't work either..

Comment: probably you are doing something wrong, can you create a plunker?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131419/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-siyah).

Answer (score 1):

In the angular,every directive create new scope.
`itemsSearch` is bind to the directive scope and its not visible to  controller.

Use it as part of object defined on `$scope` in controller.

```
    myApp.controller('SearchController', function ($http, $scope, $state) {

    $scope.objItem = {itemsSearch : ""};

     $scope.saveParentComment = function () {
          $scope.objItem.itemsSearch = "";
      };
```

HTML :

```
<input class="searchField" type="search" ng-model="objItem.itemsSearch"/>
```

Comment: Console gives me no errors. It doesn't clear it and it breaks my searching functionality even.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out :-

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="searchAll"></input> 
        <a class="clear" href="" data-ng-click="clearSearch()">X</a>

 app.controller("SearchController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.searchAll = "";

    $scope.clearSearch = function () {
        $scope.searchAll = "";
    };
});
```

Comment: Probably I am doing something wrong. I'll upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please make sure that you put `SearchController`,
Can you please try with this

```
<ion-view view-title="Testing"  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SearchController">
 <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar">
  </ion-header-bar>
     <ion-content class="scrollBar">
        <ion-searchbar class="searchBar">
           <label>
             <input class="searchField" type="search" ng-model="itemsSearch"/>
              <a class="clear" data-ng-click="saveParentComment()">X</a>
              <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
          </label>
       </ion-searchbar>
  </ion-content>
```

And Function:

```
$scope.saveParentComment = function () {
  console.log("clear");
  $scope.itemsSearch = null;
};
```

If you see clear in console log than you are sure that your function is working fine. And you can set initial value also in controller like for itemSearch like.
`$scope.itemsSearch = "Search Here";`

Comment: Well, I don't see that in my console. I have added the searchController, yet it's not working. I don't get why.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your controller. First try in console for function is working or not

```
$scope.saveParentComment = function () {
          console.log("working");
      };
```